# How old is Winry in Fullmetal Alchemist?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

I had remembered that Ed was 15 in the series, then I realized that I had no clue how old Winry was! Does it say anywhere how old she is, or do they just give an estimate?

Comment: I always assumed that Winry was the same age as Ed and any size difference between them is because Ed is a mid.....*gets an Auto-mail kick to the head*

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a light novel / short-story (though not by Arakawa) involving Ed, Al, and Winry at the village school . . . but seeing that they live in the countryside, there might be greater fudging between grade boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the [FMA Wikia](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Winry_Rockbell)

Her year of birth is mentioned as **1899**, which is the same as Edward's, although their exact birthdays are never stated. She is 15-16 years old during the course of the manga/anime, and around 18 post-timeskip.

[MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/character/63/) lists her exact birthday as June 9th, 1899. However, I don't know if there's any credible source for that.

Comment: Arakawa supposedly doesn't really give character birthdays much---this was mentioned in one of the post-chapter inserts I saw (re: Ed's birthday), which [other people](http://ladyloveandjustice.tumblr.com/post/82154053499/) have also mentioned---so the MAL date probably isn't accurate.

Comment: @Maroon, I see. Makes you wonder where MAL comes up with that stuff.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the current revision of the Wikia gives her birthday as July 26 of the same year. I wonder where people are getting these dates.

Comment: Alright, with some digging around, I've found that there is a probably reference for the 1899 year from the second manga guidebook. (See [this forum post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:eMs6jaEHylsJ:www.fullmetal-alchemist.com/forums/index.php%3Fshowtopic%3D10945%26mode%3Dthreaded%26pid%3D715216+&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk) and the discussion [here](http://www.absoluteanime.com/fullmetal_alchemist/ed.htm).)